# Links styling in CSS

Tags: html, css

Why the following styling of the link does not work ?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    a:link {color:#123456;}    /* unvisited link */
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Are you 100% positive www.google.com is unvisited? :-)

Comment: Clear browser history and retry. Or choose a random/unvisited link and retry ;)

Comment: You were right :) The link was really visited. After I cleared the browser history it worked ! I guess I don't understand the meaning of "visited link". How does the browser (for example, Firefox) remembers that the link was visited ?

Comment: The browser is just programmed so. It's code, no magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the link has been visited.

Try

```
a {color: blue;} /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color: orange;} /* visited link*/
```

If you remove the last declaration links will be blue regardless of `:visited`.

Comment: and a:hover {color:#f00;} makes it red when you hold your mouse over it.

Answer (score 3):

For some general best practices, the link styling hierarchy works like this:

```
a:link {
color: #ff0000;
}
a:visited {
color: #ff0000;
}
a:hover {
color: #cccccc;
}
a:focus {
color: #cccccc;
}
a:active {
color: #cccccc;
}
```

It's best to always apply all of these, whether you do them singly as above or like this:

```
a:link, a:visited {
color: #ff0000;
}
a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
color: #cccccc;
}
```

But regardless, the order is very important and things can be overwritten if it isn't followed.

Answer (score 0):

And you shouldn't rely on it working in the future:

http://blog.mozilla.com/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/

Comment: This is about what script querying the DOM for style information sees.  The :visited pseudo-class will still function for what the user sees (albeit with some limitations on what can be styled).  DOM queries against style of anchors will always function as if the link was unvisited.